# Attach method throws preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch

Tags: php, laravel

I have been dealing with this `ErrorException` when trying to add data to a pivot table in Laravel.

When I use a dummy array data ie 
`$service->features()->attach([1,2]);` it works but when I use values from an array variable ie. `$service->features()->attach($featuresIds);` wheareas `$featuresIds` has the value `[1,2]` it throws:

> ErrorException (E_WARNING)
>   preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array.

My **Service** model class has:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Service extends Model {

    protected $table = 'services';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('title', 'category', 'description', 'image', 'delivery_time', 'features', 'price', 'supplier', 'user_id');
    protected $visible = array('id','title', 'category', 'description', 'image', 'delivery_time', 'features', 'price', 'supplier');
    protected $dates = ['delivery_time'];

    // public function features()
    // {
    //  return $this->hasMany('Feature', 'id');
    // }

    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Supplier', 'id');
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'id');
    }


    public function user()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }


    public function features()
    {

        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

My **Feature** model class has:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Feature extends Model {

    protected $table = 'features';
    // public $timestamps = true;
    protected $fillable = array('description');
    protected $visible = array('id','description');


    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsTomany('App\Service');
    }
}
```

My controller `store` method has:

```
public function store(ServiceRequest $request)
{          
    $service = Auth::user()->services()->create($request->all());
    $featuresIds = $request->input('features');

    $service->features()->attach($featuresIds);

    return redirect('admin/service');
}
```

I have searched through many solutions online, but could not find a way to solve it. Help if you can detect what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried `dd($featuresIds);` in your controller to see if it outputs the value you're expecting? There's no reason for it not to work when the variable contains the same value you put in manually.

Comment: Thanks Bogdan, I had a features column in my services table which was of type VARCHAR thus the error. I also had to remove the features key word in my protected list of arrays for it to work. The error had nothing to do with the $featuresIds which was right it was all my stupid mistake.